# Traverse the array and each time you encounter and change the value in java

Tags: java, arrays

**if  Take an array of size 10 and take user inputs.how can i Traverse the array and each time you encounter '6' or '7', replace them with 60 and 70 respectively in java??**

Comment: Can you please show us your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this,

```
int[] input = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    if(input[i]==6 || input[i]==7)
        input[i]*=10;

  //Printing

for(int i : input)
   System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplistic approach. Loop through the array and check each positions value. If it's a 6 or 7 replace as expected.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

            if(array[i] == 6){
                array[i] = 60;
            }
            else if(array[i] == 7){
                array[i] = 70;
            }

        }

        for(int i : array){
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }
```